# Scrapy, scraping text in HTML tag when there are no quotation marks?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

**UPDATE:** this number 48 is showed in "Inspect" in Chrome, but not in "View Page Source". Now understand that it is generated by JavaScript and that is why I can not extract it.

This is part of HTML that I am trying to scrape

```
<span class="value">
     <span class="base-entity-display-count">48</span> 
     "times"
</span>
```

Problem is that I can not get this 48 number.
I think that problem is because there are no "" around 48.
Because I can get "times" text with no problems, and the only difference that I can see is that there are no "" around 48.

This is code that is working for "times":

```
response.xpath('.//span[@class="value"]/text()').extract_first()
>>> u'<span class="value"><span class="base-entity-display-count"></span>times</span>'
```

For 48:

```
response.xpath('.//span[@class="base-entity-display-count"]').extract_first()
>>> u'<span class="base-entity-display-count"></span>'
```

As you can see, 48 is missing.

Does anybody have some solution or idea?

Comment: If you can get "times",  can you just scrap the whole span, and then manually get the number by yourself?

Comment: Regarding your edit. 
You should either expand on your answer with website url or open up a new question. 

Often when nodes are unpacked by javascript you can find the values in the body under some data storage json :)

Comment: You can also check the 'Network' in chrome devtools, 48 may come from an web api (XHR) response.

Comment: @Granitosaurus I did not include original URL because it is not English. If somebody wants to take a look it is at https://www.njuskalo.hr/nekretnine/visoka-60-m2-2-k-mala-zgrada-120.000-eur-oglas-25399798.

Comment: @pennyliangliping I will ignore it for now maybe, cost/benefit too high.

Comment: @TianyunLing I found out that it is done via JavaScript.

Comment: @WebOrCode not it's not, don't give up - it's surprisingly simple! Check my answer :)

Comment: @Granitosaurus I can only say thanks. And I should really learn Regular Expressions.

Comment: You should! It's a small skill but it comes in handy almost every day and it's doesn't seem to be going away anywhere either!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the body of the page and search for your number you can see that there's some embeded json.
[image]

To solve this you can:

1. find embeded json with regex:

   ```
   import re
   # select everything between "ap.boot.push(" and ");"
   data = re.findall('app.boot.push\((\{.+?\})\);', response.body_as_unicode())
   ```
2. load up json and parse it with python to find the values you want:

   ```
   import json
   data = [json.loads(d) for d in data]
   for d in data:
       if d.get('name') == 'BaseEntityDetails':
           print(d['values']['displayCountText'])
   #prints: 66
   ```